# Test-Path / System.IO.Directory::Exists not working as expected

Tags: powershell, acl, directory-permissions

I'm having trouble using the Powershell CmdLet Test-Path.

I created a Share on a Server (\\Servername\MyShare$), which allows one Group of users to just create a file and append data, while others users can just read and delete these files. The first group is not allowed to do anything else, including Read-Permissions, Read-Attributes and so on.

If I do a Test-Path on this folder as member of the "drop files only" group, it returns false. Even `[System.IO.Directory]::Exists()` returns false.

I am searching for a way to test if a directory exists without the need to have Read-Permissions or Read-Attributes rights. Any ideas?

Is this the correct behaviour of those two methods?

Regards,
teamoo

Comment: It would help to see the PowerShell code you're actually using.

Comment: @beefarino The code is really simple: `Test-Path "\\server\Share$"` I even tried this with the same result: `[System.IO.Directory]::Exists("\\server\Share$")` both return false, while the Share actually exists, but I'm not allowed to access it, which is not a reason (in my opinion) to return False with both methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, if nobody want to venture ...

Here is a solution :

I'am not allowed to access to directory `.\f1\f2` and `.\f1\f3` does not exists.

```
PS C:\Silogix> Get-ChildItem .\f1\f2 -ErrorAction silentlycontinue
PS C:\Silogix> $Error[0].exception
L'accès au chemin d'accès 'C:\Silogix\f1\f2' est refusé.
PS C:\Temp\Temp> $Error[0].exception.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     UnauthorizedAccessException              System.SystemException

PS C:\Silogix> Get-ChildItem .\f1\f3 -ErrorAction silentlycontinue
PS C:\Silogix> $Error[0].exception.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     ItemNotFoundException
```

So if you test `$Error[0].exception.gettype()` after the `Get-Item` you can understand why it's not accessible, so if it exists or not. You can call that "bricolage", but it's also a solution. Sorry for the french in the example.

Comment: Thanks for your code. I came up with a similar solution: `try {gc "\\server\Share$" -erroraction Stop} catch [System.SystemException] {if ($_.Exception.gettype() -eq [System.UnauthorizedAccessException]) {#access is denied}}` Would anyone consider this behaviour (answering that a directory does not exists although it does) a bug?

Comment: Not a bug, the _semantic_ of `Test-Path`is just not the one wich is documented. In fact `Test-Path` means is this item exists and can be read.