# Powershell - Trying to test-path against a string that resembles a variable name

Tags: variables, powershell

The company I work for prefixes all their admin level accounts with a $ sign. Trouble, I know.

I'm trying to use `test-path` to see if a folder exists like so:

```
$username = read-host "Enter Login ID:"
```

I type `$adminsdb` into the box and hit ok

```
##### Find TS Profile #####
$TSProfile_exist = test-path "\\server\tsprofiles$\$username"
```

The folder DOES exist but... `$TSProfile_exist` is coming up False

How do I handle the `$` in the username? I'm building this app to bring up quick stats on users in the environment.  We also have service accounts that are prefixed with # signs.

Answer (score 4):

The way to handle special caracters in PowerShell is using **`** (backtick)

```
$TSProfile_exist = test-path "\\server\tsprofiles$\$username"
```

becomes

```
$TSProfile_exist = test-path "\\server\tsprofiles`$\$username"
```

**Be careful** a trick with `Test-Path`, is that it semantic is not that the directory exists, but is that the directory is readable. In other words if you do not have access to the directory you test, you will receive `false` even if  the directory exists. [See this other entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632908/test-path-system-io-directoryexists-not-working-as-expected/5644870#comment-6456790).

Comment: So is there a way to test a path without having to enumerate the entire directory tree and searching by -match operations?

Comment: You can use `Get-ChildItem -Path Where-To-Begin-Search -Include "Searched.File" -Recurse`

Comment: This also requires a long wait time while the directory is listed... is there anything test-path like that is faster than get-childitem?

Comment: I d'on't understand. Do you want to test the existence of a file in a cetain path ? You can perhaps ask another question here, we are not in the same subject.

Comment: Your earlier suggestion to use get-childitem works however this is very slow as the get-childitem cmdlet lists all the directories in a given location.  test-path seems to bypass this by testing the path directly.  Is there another way to accomplish the same speed as test-path without the gotchas of directory permissions?

Answer (score 3):

The other alternative is to use single-quoted strings; powershell will not expand variables in this case.

```
test-path '\\server\path\$username'
```

-Oisin